# how to parse a time in Ruby which takes a string in HH:MM and calculate seconds into the day

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have method which takes a string in HH:MM format and it should calculate how many seconds into the day it is

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.strptime(myString, "%H:%M") - Time.now.beginning_of_day
```